# How to structure and import angularjs2 + typescript app with external js libs?

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

### My choices:

I'm new to angularjs2 but have done a project in angularjs1. I'm also new to typescript. I have followed typescript and angularjs2 tutorials. I have never used systemjs or requirejs.

I want to build a web application (preferably one-page) using angularjs2 and typescript with some external libraries like fullcalendar and soundmanager2. I also like to use jade and sass as my view and styling engines/whatev.
**I would like to make this usable as plain html for opening in browser**

Let's say I have chosen systemjs for my "universal dynamic module loader".

### My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.44/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }
      });
      System.import('./app.ts');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

.

```
import {bootstrap, Component, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <h2>My Heroes</h2>
      `,
      directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})

class AppComponent {
  public title = "Tour of Heroes";
}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

### My question:

The code above is from angularjs2 tutorial.

- **The biggest question:** how do I combine my js libraries with my typescript angularjs2 code? Do I compile typescript or import via systemjs? How do I get angular to recognize these libraries and their appis?
- Why am I using Systemjs if I also use script tags for importing?
- Do I add sass as compiled css in head via  or do I add the compiled css in @Component?
- What do I do with my jades? Do I compile them as well (I'm more wondering for my partial views) or do I add them via angular (does angular have jade support)?

I understand angularjs is *opininized* so I suppose everything has it's place somewhere inside angular code but by god I'm having hard time organizing this.

Comment: according to my view, instead of including css in head you can use separate css for different component using styleUrls in the `@view`. or u can also use `@import` for adding css in the template itself.also there are some more way of styling like inline and internal as we use in the previous projects.